# Is the emmeans (R) intercept-only function broken?

Tags: r, emmeans

I've noticed that emmeans (in R) isn't working for an intercept-only estimate after the latest update.

Reproducible example:

```
test=lm(mpg~1,mtcars)
library(emmeans)
emmeans::emmeans(test,~1)
```

The output on 2 of my machines (windows and Linux) is:

```
> emmeans::emmeans(test,~1)
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ".wgt.", value = 2) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Is this a known issue, or have I messed up my system somehow?
This used to work I believe.

It *does* work if you include a variable:

```
test2=lm(mpg~as.factor(cyl),mtcars)
emmeans(test2,~cyl)
```

Thanks very much for the help in advance.

Comment: It is working fine for me `emmeans::emmeans(test,~1)#
 1       emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 overall   20.1 1.07 31     17.9     22.3`

Comment: Can you please check wehterh you have the same version of 'emmeans' as I have

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I have 1.4.7, I'll revert to 1.4.6 and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine with `emmeans - 1.4.6` on `macOS Catalina 10.15.4` and `R 4.0`

```
emmeans::emmeans(test,~1)
# 1       emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# overall   20.1 1.07 31     17.9     22.3

#Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: A change from version 1.4.7 to 1.4.6 did fix the problem. I would upvote this answer if I could. I'll see if I can make the comment on the emmeans github page. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the fix for issue [#197](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/197) -- and incorporated in CRAN version 1.47 -- created the issue [(#206)](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/206) that we see here. I think I have them both fixed now:

```r
require(emmeans)
## Loading required package: emmeans

#206...
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

emmeans(warp.lm, "1")
##  1       emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  overall   28.1 1.49 48     25.2     31.1
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: wool, tension 
## Confidence level used: 0.95

emmeans(warp.lm, "1", by = "wool")
## wool = A:
##  1       emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  overall   31.0 2.11 48     26.8     35.3
## 
## wool = B:
##  1       emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  overall   25.3 2.11 48     21.0     29.5
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: tension 
## Confidence level used: 0.95


#197...
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ poly(Petal.Length,2), data = iris)

emtrends(model, ~ 1, "Petal.Length", max.degree = 2)
## degree = linear:
##  1       Petal.Length.trend     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
##  overall             0.4474 0.0180 147   0.4119    0.483
## 
## degree = quadratic:
##  1       Petal.Length.trend     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
##  overall             0.0815 0.0132 147   0.0554    0.108
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Users who need this now can install from github via

```r
remotes::install_github("rvlenth/emmeans")
```